# Promotion price or promotional price

Tags: grammar

> **Promotion price** only available at XYZ store.

Is "**promotion price**" wrongly used here?

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELL! Can you add a little bit more context to your question? Do you want to understand the difference between **promotion price** and **promotional price** ?

Comment: @Liiuc Hi, yes. Would like to know the difference between promotion price and promotional price. In the given example, should it be "promotion price" or "promotional price"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence should be:

> **Promotional price** only available at XYZ store

[Promotional](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/promotional) is used when you intended to advertise something while [Promotion](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/promotion) is used to express activities that advertise  something.

to get more in depth differences check out this [link](https://www.askdifference.com/promotional-vs-promotion/)